# Error while posting something from Esp32(Micropython) to firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to use firebase with Micropython. It doesn't matter how many times I do this
`print(firebase.get(URL))`. If I use `firebase.put(URL, datas)` or `firebase.patch(URL, datas)` then it successfully posts that data, but if I try to read the data `print(firebase.get(URL))` then this error pops up.

Firebase library: https://github.com/vishal-android-freak/firebase-micropython-esp32

Code:

```
import network
import ufirebase as firebase
from time import sleep

URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/'

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
if not wlan.active() or not wlan.isconnected():
    wlan.active(True)
    print('connecting to: xxxx')
    wlan.connect('xxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx')
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        pass
print('network config:', wlan.ifconfig())
datas = {'Shape': {'hos': 'fse', 'xxe': 'ter'}, 'Wps': 'Wps'}

firebase.put(URL, datas)
sleep(5)
print(firebase.get(URL))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "ufirebase.py", line 124, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 116, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 62, in request
OSError: [Errno 12] ENOMEM
MicroPython v1.18 on 2022-01-17; 4MB/OTA module with ESP32
Type "help()" for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it problem is with urequests library, if you can switchback to usocket and close the socket before timeout then works fine. For urequests you need to have a board with spiram. For non-spiram based borads here is a good firebase library based on sockets [micropython-firebase-realtime-database](https://github.com/ckoever/micropython-firebase-realtime-database)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `firebase.get(URL)` and getting an out of memory error.

This call returns the entire contents of the database. Apparently this is more than the amount of RAM available to MicroPython (which isn't a lot). `ENOMEM` means "no memory" - Python has run out of memory.

You need to change the call to request just what you're trying to fetch. In this case you might try

```
print(firebase.get(URL + 'Shape'))
print(firebase.get(URL + 'Was'))
```

You can refer to [the library's documentation](https://github.com/vishal-android-freak/firebase-micropython-esp32) to see how to better use the `get()` method.

Comment: Well still same issue, but your answer is helpful, so it means I need to change esp32 model and it'll work right?? 
I'm using esp wroom-32
which esp 32 should I use you think?? 
thanks

Comment: No, I mean you need to not try to download more data than fits into the available memory. If the only way to do that is to use a different CPU then that seems like there's a problem in how you're interacting with Firebase. Also, all ESP32s have the same amount of RAM. You can get some boards with additional PSRAM on them; I'm not sure how well Micropython interacts with it. The best solution is to query Firebase in a way that returns smaller amounts of data.